# Editing a contact's lastname not working on some APIs

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I have a code to edit a contact's last name to "*anyname*" and it works fine on some APIs and doesn't work on the others. The main code starts by touching a button with this code:

```
android:onClick="start"
```

and the main code (void start):

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(1)});
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "anyname");
ops.add(builder.build());

try
{
    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

that `{String.valueOf(1)}` is for selecting the first contact. it only doesn't work on these APIs:**`4.3 (API 18) - 4.4.4 (API 19) - 6 (API 23) - 7 (API 24)** and **7.1 (API 25)**, but does work on other APIs fine and can change the family name. and about error or exceptions, I don't get any exception on any of them and don't get any thing (in the monitor and run windows) for for API 18 and 19. but as I thought it maybe needed to see all monitor and run lines, I copied the lines for API 24 into a notepad. These are the lines that appear after I touch the button not the lines while application is debugging or running. When I touch the button, nothing show up and application doesn't do anything.

https://uploadfiles.io/0sz9n

The other APIs got these lines too. Due to this, I only copied the API 24. Can you figure out what is the problem?

Comment: The log you've posted shows the error: `SecurityException ... requires READ_CONTACTS or WRITE_CONTACTS`, you should request that permission on your manifest, and also request it in runtime on Android M and above. see https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Also, you should avoid using try/catch to hide Exceptions unless you realize what you're doing. Otherwise you should let the exception crash your app so you'll know what to fix

Comment: Thanks man! it worked! i add these codes before ArrayList.

Comment: @marmor`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                first);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS},
                second);`

Comment: @marmornow i have a couple of questions:     1: does the added code enough?    2: sometimes i need to touch the button several times to operate, i mean sometimes when i touch button only 1 time, it doesn't work, when i touch it again and again, it work. could it be due to the contact's ID? i entered the number 1 for ID. do the contact's IDs dynamic and change every time that i run the app? for example one time ID number 1 refers to contact "a" and another time it refers to contact "b" ?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Putting this as an answer:

The log you've posted shows the error:

> SecurityException ... requires READ_CONTACTS or WRITE_CONTACTS

you should request that permission on your manifest, and also request it in runtime on Android M and above. see http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Regarding your follow-up questions:

There's no need for two permission requests, you can merge the two into one:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, 
    new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS }, first);
```

Contact IDs may change, but it's **very rare** and most likely not related to the code not working issue.
You should add some logs in your code to see where the flow stops when you click the button and it doesn't work.
Also, make sure you don't have any try/catch in your code unless you're expecting an exception and know how to handle it, otherwise it may lead to flow "doing nothing" without any explanation (due to crashes)

**EDIT**

Following the issues mentioned in the comments, here's how you should handle the permissions request flow:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public void start(View v) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ permission.WRITE_CONTACTS }, 12345);
        } else {
            // WE ALREADY HAVE PERMISSION, RUN THE MAIN FUNCTION
            editContacts();
        }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if ((requestCode == 12345) && (grantResults.length == 1) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            // WE GOT THE PERMISSION, RUN THE MAIN FUNCTION
            editContacts();
        }
    }

    public void editContacts() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, but 2 problems, first as i'm amateur i really don't know how to use log. but i think the problem could be here:    when i remove the Try/Catch, this line of code:   `getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);`   get this error:   `Unhandled exceptions: android.os.RemoteException, android.content.OperationApplicationException` ----- then i pressed Alt + Enter and my function that runs all these codes changed to: `public void start(View v) throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException`

Comment: that line of code fixed but when i run the app on API 24 (the only one that i tested) application got an error and close, and this is new runtime codes in a notepad:  https://ufile.io/ltr15

Comment: And btw, the code now works on API 21 (5.0.0) which doesn't need getting permission. when you run it on API 24 for first time, after it got error and close, the permission prompt pop ups and ask you, if you chose Deny, this process would repeat next time and the application crash again, but the weird part is when you chose Allow (after application close for first time) the next time you run the application, it won't close and won't got error and works fine!

Comment: it seems it only has problem on getting permission and error on that, i mean it seems it only needs to have Allow/Deny window opened for one time, then you chose Allow and it will ok next time!

Comment: Any solution? i really reached dead-end for this :(

Comment: sounds like you're not performing the permission request flow properly. i'll add something to my answer